# wpf application which shows all forms in one window

Tags: c#, wpf

hi I want to make a wpf c# application which shows every form(Ex:- user registration, reports , etc..)in one window in other words I want to make an application which have one window and every user control appears and closed there when I want just like games in some games like middle of honor warfighter they have one window and if we chose option option buttons appear in the same window and if we chose graphics that graphic page content appear in that same window.

and I want to know is there any frame work or special method is there which I should fallow other than putting wpf controls one over another and changing there visibility and isopen status.If there is any examples please give me a link

Comment: This is pretty much the whole concept of WPF MVVM, multiple ViewModels with Datatemplates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ContentControl for holding any element. also PRISM is best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF Popup forms below are some links for more info:-

http://www.dzone.com/articles/understanding-wpf-popups

---

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11700/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [MDI Control](http://mdicontainer.codeplex.com). It helps you to show any kind of usercontrol in one container as window.